# Do installs of multiple-disc games to the hard drive still require you to change the disc?

Tags: xbox-360

On the Xbox 360, along with the option to install games to the hard drive, you can also apparently install multiple-disc games to the hard drive, but I haven't tried this.

For instance, L.A. Noire and Rage have 3 discs, and Dead Space 2 has 2 discs.

I know you have to have a disc in the drive to start an installed game. If I install all discs to the drive, will I still have to switch out discs when the game gets to the portion requiring a new disc, despite the fact that they are all installed?

Comment: And a bonus point if you can tell me if using disc or disk is correct.

Comment: [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8474/is-there-a-difference-between-disc-and-disk](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8474/is-there-a-difference-between-disc-and-disk)

Comment: Bonus points to Matthew, he's quite a linguist, or good with the Google. Either way, thanks. Guess I had it right then.

Comment: Re: English question. Depending on whether you are approaching this from a prescriptive or descriptive point of view. If you have the former, then you'd argue one over another. If the latter, you'd accept both as both are in wide use and can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with a few exceptions.  Forza 3, for example, comes on two discs but one of the discs is data, so if installed, disc changing is not necessary.

The reason you need to insert each disc is a way of making sure you possess the physical game disc at the time you are playing.

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Comment: Forza 3 is actually the only exception I can recall.  Every other game I can think of requires the disc to be in the drive.  A quick search of the innertubes comes up with no other exceptions.

Comment: Great, +1 then :)

Comment: Makes sense. I understand the need to have the one disc in to verify that you have it, but was hoping Disc 1 would be all that's needed and the switching wasn't.

Comment: Though it would be nice if companies trusted us gamers, they are probably trying to prevent two people from playing the same copy of a game at the same time.  For example: we're roommates and I play the first disc of LA Noire and when I move on to the second disc, you could then play the first disc.

Comment: Not wanting to start a war here, @ChristopherRayl, all that DRM does is penalize people that don't cheat to begin with. A pirate on a modded x-box would never have to worry about it (granted they probably wouldn't have to worry about x-box live either).

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you that some will go the extra mile and can subvert this protection, but it is probably aimed more at the casual enthusiast, who won't ever mod their 360, but would share copies of the game if the initial investment is low.   Pirates will be pirates, and DRM will continue to burden legitimate users more.

Comment: @ChristopherRayl - Castlevania: Lords of Shadow requires you to have the correct disc in the drive for the content you are playing, but will happily boot from either disc. Hence your situation of sharing a game with a roommate would be possible, albeit one where you'd have to swap discs at appropriate moments.